# Question Relating to the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I have the following question:

Suppose $X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_{12}$ are identical independent uniform random variables on $[0,1]$. Let the sample mean(lets call it $m$) = $\frac{1}{12}(X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_{12})$. Use the central limit theorem to estimate the following: $P\left ( m \leq \frac{1}{3}\right )$.

I am taken to assume that the population mean ($E[X_i] = \mu = \frac{b+a }{ 2}$ for a uniform RV) is $\frac{1}{2}$ but as we have $12$ random variables, using the additive property we have $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 12  = 6$. Also $Var[X_i]= \frac{(b+a)^2}{12} = \frac{1}{12} \cdot 12$(12 random variables) $= 1$ and standard deviation(std) $= 1$

Using the central limit theorem or normal approximation: $\left [\frac{m-µ}{\frac{std }{\sqrt{n}} }\right ] \leq \frac{1}{3}$. However I ran into a problem after this as the $P(Z\leq z)$ returns a incredibly big $z$ value of $P(Z\leq-19.63)$ which does not seem correct. I assume it has something to do with $m = \frac{1}{12} \cdot (X_1+X_2+\ldots +X_{12})$ as I am not sure why that was included in the question.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does standardizing a random variable make it normal?

Comment: Call the sample mean $\bar{X}$. This has mean $\frac{1}{2}$ and standard deviation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}$. The probability that $\bar{X}$ is less than $\frac{1}{3}$ is (cross fingers) approximately the probability that $Z\le \frac{1/3 -1/2}{1/\sqrt{12}}$. The number on the right is quite reasonable, definitely not $-19.63$.

Comment: Note that the mean of $\frac{1}{12}(X_1+\cdots+X_{12})$ is $\frac{6}{12}=\frac{1}{2}$. You used $6$.

Comment: If you sum 12 indep. obs. from UNIF(0, 1) and subtract 6, you have a random variable with mean 0 and variance 1, that is very close to normal by CLT, but it has no values outside of (-6,6). Formerly, this idea was used in simulation work to generate standard normal random variables (approx.). Nowadays the exact Box-Muller method is used to generate standard normals.